# Use of the condition "compact' in a proof

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, amenability

> Let $\Gamma$ be an abelian amenable group acting on a compact space $X$. Show that there is an invariant Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Proof: Fix $x_0 \in X$. For $f \in C(X)$ define $g_f(t)=f(t.x_0)$. Then $g_f \in l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$. Now define $\psi:C(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\psi(f)=\mu(g_f)$, where $\mu$ is the left invariant state on $l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$, the existence of which is given by the amenability of $\Gamma$. It is easy to see that $\psi \in C(X)^*$. By Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $\nu$ on $X$ such that $$\psi(f)=\mu(g_f)=\int_X f d\nu$$

We already know that for $s \in \Gamma$, (Note: For $s \in \Gamma,s.\nu(E)=\nu(s^{-1}E)$)

$$\int_X f(sx)d\nu(x)=\int_Xf(x)d(s.\nu(x))$$

If we define $T:X \to X$ by $T(x)=sx$, then the above equation tells us that $$\int_X f\circ T(x)d\nu(x)=\int_Xf(x)d(s.\nu(x))$$

Now $$g_{f\circ T}(t)=f\circ T(t.x_0)=f(st.x_0)=s^{-1}.g_f(t)$$ gives us that $$\int_X fd(s\nu)=\mu(g_{f \circ T})=\mu(s^{-1}.g_f)=\mu(g_f)=\int_Xf d\nu, \forall f \in C(X)$$
which gives us that $s.\nu=\nu$ for all $s \in \Gamma$.

> My Question: What goes wrong in my proof when $X$ being compact is replaced by $X$ being Locally Compact?. I was thinking that I can do the same argument with the modification of $C_0(X)$ in place of $C(X)$. But it can't be true since I know that when $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ by translation, then the action doesn't induce any invariant Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what goes wrong in your example of $\mathbb Z$ acting on $X=\mathbb R$ by translation. Or even simpler, take $X=\mathbb Z$.

The state $\mu:\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)\to\mathbb C$ is basically a [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) (though two-sided). You can show that if $g:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$ tends to $0$ at infinity, then $\mu(g)=0$, and in particular the measure $\psi:C_0(X)\to \mathbb C$ you get is just the zero measure. In other words the problem is that $C_0(X)$ isn't unital.

You could extend to look at all bounded continuous functions, $\psi:C_b(X)\to \mathbb C$, but then the Riesz representation theorem fails and the functional you get isn't inner regular; it's more like a Banach limit.

Edit: here is a proof that a continuous shift-invariant linear function $g:c_0(\mathbb Z)\to\mathbb C$ must be zero (where $c_0$ means functions tending to zero, with sup norm). Let $e_i\in c_0(\mathbb Z)$ denote the function with $e_i(i)=1$ and $e_i(j)=0$ for $j\neq i$. Using linearity and shift invariance, $g(e_1)$ equals $g(\tfrac 1 N (e_1+\dots+e_N))$ for any $N$. Taking the limit as $N\to\infty$ gives $g(e_1)=g(0)=0$. By linearity and shift invariance, $g$ is zero on functions of finite support, but those are dense in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @How do I show that the measure such obtained is a zero measure?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: if you accept that $\mu(g)=0$ for any $g$ tending to zero at infinity, then the definition $\psi(f)=\mu(g_f)$ shows that $\psi$ is zero for all $f\in C_0(X)$. To show $\mu(g)=0$ is a simple exercise (using positivity, linearity and shift invariance) but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking. More importantly, the argument to show the measure ISN'T zero fails, because you don't have constant functions.

Comment: I am not asking about the proof dealing with the measure when $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}$. My question is how do I show the same thing when an arbitrary group $G$ acts on a locally compact space $X$?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: you won't always get the zero measure for non-compact $X$ e.g. trivial action would just assign unit weight at $x_0$

Comment: Then where does my proof go wrong for Locally compact spaces?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: to see where a proof goes wrong, it suffices to look at a counterexample, which is what I've done - what goes wrong is that you haven't guaranteed the measure is non-trivial on $C_0(X)$. Maybe you have a different question in mind, like "if the closure of the orbit of $x_0$ is non-compact, can the induced measure be non-trivial?"